# CPU performance counter not working in Windows 10 guest, VMWare ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, cpu-usage, performance-counters

CPU performance counters are not working inside my Windows 10 guest virtual machine. I run a bare metal VMWare ESXi (6.5) host.

As can be seen from the screen shot all other non-CPU performance counters are working, even the pass-through GPU performance. But CPU shows always as 0% which is obviously not correct.

What am I missing here?

[image]
[image]